# Recuperar campo sem include/require

Tags: php, html, mysql, mpdf

Tenho um relatório criado no mPDF que realiza um select através da seguinte função que é encontrada na página "registra_pessoa.php":

```
include_once("registra_pessoa.php");
$pessoas = filtraPessoas();
```

Segue função:

```
function filtraPessoas(){
    $grupo = '';
    $banco = abrirBanco();
    if(isset($_POST['nomefiltrar'])){
    $teste = $_POST['nomefiltrar'];
    }else{
        $teste = '';
    }
    $sql = "SELECT id, nome, DATE_FORMAT(nascimento, '%d/%m/%Y') AS data_formatada, endereco, telefone FROM pessoa WHERE nome LIKE '%$teste%' ";
    $resultado = $banco->query($sql);
    $banco->close();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
        $grupo[] = $row;
    }
    return $grupo;
}
```

Através do campo "nomefiltrar", o relatório deveria filtrar, porém, percebi que a variável '$teste' não está recebendo o valor contido no campo.

Tentei dar um include_once('consulta_clientes.php') (página que contém este campo), porém, retorna erro porque o mPDF usa suas próprias tags de , etc:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\despesas\consulta_clientes.php:180) in C:\xampp\htdocs\despesas\MPDF57\mpdf.php on line 7447

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\despesas\consulta_clientes.php:180) in C:\xampp\htdocs\despesas\MPDF57\mpdf.php on line 1736
mPDF error: Some data has already been output to browser, can't send PDF file
```

Segue form:

```
<div class="container">
        <form hidden name="filtroClientes" action="consulta_clientes.php" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="nomefiltrar" style="color:#E4CDAC; font-size: 17px; font-family:Arial">Nome</label>
                <p>
                <input type="text" class="teste" id="nomefiltrar" name="nomefiltrar" />
            </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="acao" value="filtrar" />
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-custom btn-roxo">Filtrar</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

@Edit:

```
consulta_clientes.php :

<?php include_once("registra_pessoa.php");
    $grupo = filtraPessoas();



    if(!$_SESSION['usuario']){
        header('Location: index.php?erro=1');
    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>



        <script type="text/javascript">
            function ocultaForm(tag){
                $(tag).show();
            }



        </script>

        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <title>Despesas</title>

        <!-- jquery - link cdn -->

          <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
          integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

          <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mask.min.js"/></script>


        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <!-- bootstrap - link cdn -->
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="estilo.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>

<!-- Static navbar -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse navbar-transparente">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#barranavegacao">
                        <span class="sr-only">Alternar navegação</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>

                    <a href="home.php" class="navbar-brand">
                       <span class="img-logo">Despesas</span>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="barranavegacao">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                      <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
                      <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Cadastro
                        <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a href="inserir_pessoa.php">Cadastro de Clientes</a></li>
                          <li><a href="inserir_produto.php">Cadastro de Produtos</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li class="dropdown active">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Consultas
                        <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a href="consulta_clientes.php">Consulta de Clientes</a></li>
                          <li><a href="consulta_produtos.php">Consulta de Produtos</a></li>
                          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="consulta_contas.php">Consulta de Contas a Pagar</a></li>
                          <li><a href="consulta_contas_receber.php">Consulta de Contas a Receber</a></li>
                      </ul>
                      <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Financeiro
                        <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a href="inserir_conta.php">Contas a Pagar</a></li>
                          <li><a href="inserir_recebimento.php">Contas a Receber</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>


                    </ul>

                      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
          <a href="">Ajuda</a>
        </li>
        <li class="divisor" role="separator">
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="sair.php">Sair</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>



            </div>
        </nav>
        <br><br><br><br><br>


        <div class="container">
        <div class="thumb">
        <a href="pdf_clientes.php" target="_blank">
        <img src="imagens/printer.png">
        </a>
        <div class="desc"><span style="color:white">Imprimir Relatório</span></div>
        </div>

        <div class="thumb">
            <img id="filtraresultados" name="filtraresultados" src="imagens/search.png" style="cursor:pointer" "/>
        <div class="desc"><span style="color:white">Filtrar Resultados</span></div>
        </div>


        </div>


        <br>

        <div class="container">
        <form hidden name="filtroClientes" action="consulta_clientes.php" method="POST">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="nomefiltrar" style="color:#E4CDAC; font-size: 17px; font-family:Arial">Nome</label>
                <p>

                <input type="text" class="teste" id="nomefiltrar" name="nomefiltrar" />


            </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="acao" value="filtrar" />
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-custom btn-roxo">Filtrar</button>
    </div>
</form>
<br>



        <script>
            filtraresultados.addEventListener("click", function() {
                ocultaForm('form');
            }, false);
        </script>

        <script>
            filtraresultados.addEventListener("click", function() {
                ocultaFormBotao('input');
            }, false);
        </script>






        <div class="container divconsultas">

                <table class="table">
            <thread>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" style="color:white; font-size: 17px; font-family:Tahoma">Nome</td>
                    <td align="center" style="color:white; font-size: 17px; font-family:Tahoma">Data de nascimento</td>
                    <td align="center" style="color:white; font-size: 17px; font-family:Tahoma">Telefone</td>
                    <td align="center" style="color:white; font-size: 17px; font-family:Tahoma">Endereço</td>
                    <td align="center" style="color:white; font-size: 17px; font-family:Tahoma">Editar</td>
                    <td align="center" style="color:white; font-size: 17px; font-family:Tahoma">Excluir</td>
                </tr>
            </thread>
                <?php
                if (is_array($grupo) || is_object($grupo)){
                foreach($grupo as $pessoa){
                 ?>

                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" style="color:white; font-size: 15px; font-family:Tahoma"> <?=$pessoa["nome"]?> </td>
                        <td align="center" style="color:white; font-size: 15px; font-family:Tahoma"> <?=$pessoa["data_formatada"]?> </td>
                        <td align="center" style="color:white; font-size: 15px; font-family:Tahoma"> <?=$pessoa["telefone"]?> </td>
                        <td align="center" style="color:white; font-size: 15px; font-family:Tahoma"> <?=$pessoa["endereco"]?></td>
                        <td align="center" style="color:white; font-size: 15px; font-family:Tahoma">

                             <form align="center" action="alterar_pessoa.php" name="alterar" method="POST">
                                <input type="hidden" name="id" value=<?=$pessoa["id"]?>>
                                <input type="submit" class="btn editar cor" value="Editar" name="Editar" class="btn btn-default">
                             </form>

                        </td>
                        <td>

                            <form align="center" action="registra_pessoa.php" name="excluir" method="POST">
                                <input type="hidden" name="id" value=<?=$pessoa["id"]?>>
                                <input type="hidden" name="acao" value="excluir"/>
                                <input type="submit" class="btn editar excluir" onclick="msgSucesso()" value="Excluir" name="excluir" class="btn btn-default">
                            </form>

                        </td>
                    </tr>


                </div>

                    <script>
                        function msgSucesso(){
                            alert('Pessoa excluida com sucesso');
                        }
                    </script>


                <?php
                }
            }else{
                echo('Ainda não existem clientes cadastrados');
            }

                ?>

            </table>
        </div>




    </body>
</html>
```

Registra_pessoa.php:

```
<?php

session_start();


require_once('db.class.php');

if(!$_SESSION['usuario']){
    header('Location: index.php?erro=1');
}

if(isset($_POST['acao'])){
    if($_POST['acao'] == "inserir"){
    inserirPessoa();
    }
    if($_POST['acao'] == "alterar"){
        alterarPessoas();
    }
    if($_POST['acao'] == "excluir"){
        excluirPessoas();
    }
    if($_POST['acao'] == "filtrar"){
        filtraPessoas();
    }

}


function abrirBanco(){
    $conexao = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "despesas");
    return $conexao;
}

function valortotal(){
    $grupo = selectContas();
    foreach($grupo as $contas){
        $valortotal += $contas["valor"];
    }
}


function inserirPessoa(){

     $nome = $_POST['nome'];
     $datanascimento = $_POST['nascimento'];
     $endereco = $_POST['endereco'];
     $telefone = $_POST["telefone"];
     $id = $_POST['id'];


    $banco = abrirBanco();
    $sql = "INSERT INTO pessoa(nome,nascimento,endereco,telefone) VALUES ('$nome', '$datanascimento', '$endereco', '$telefone')";

    $banco->query($sql);
    $banco->close();

    header('Location: home.php');

}



function filtraPessoas(){
    $grupo = '';
    $banco = abrirBanco();
    $teste = $_POST['nomefiltrar'];

    $sql = "SELECT id, nome, DATE_FORMAT(nascimento, '%d/%m/%Y') AS data_formatada, endereco, telefone FROM pessoa WHERE nome LIKE '%$teste%' ";
    $resultado = $banco->query($sql);
    $banco->close();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
        $grupo[] = $row;
    }
    return $grupo;
}

function selectIdPessoas($id){
    $banco = abrirBanco();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM pessoa WHERE id = ".$id;
    $resultado = $banco->query($sql);
    $banco->close();
    $pessoa = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
    return $pessoa;
}

function alterarPessoas(){

     $nome = $_POST['nome'];
     $id = $_POST['id'];
     $datanascimento = $_POST['nascimento'];
     $endereco = $_POST['endereco'];
     $telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
     $id = $_POST['id'];
    $banco = abrirBanco();
    $sql = "UPDATE pessoa set nome = '$nome', nascimento = '$datanascimento', endereco = '$endereco', telefone = '$telefone' WHERE id= '$id' ";
    $banco->query($sql);
    $banco->close();

    header('Location: consulta_clientes.php');


}

function excluirPessoas(){

     $nome = $_POST['nome'];
     $id = $_POST['id'];
     $datanascimento = $_POST['nascimento'];
     $endereco = $_POST['endereco'];
     $telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
     $id = $_POST['id'];
    $banco = abrirBanco();
    $sql = "DELETE FROM pessoa WHERE id= '$id' ";
    $banco->query($sql);
    $banco->close();

    header('Location: consulta_clientes.php');


}


?>
```

pdf_clientes.php:

```
<?php
    include_once("registra_pessoa.php");
    include("./MPDF57/mpdf.php");
    $nome_filtrar = (isset($_POST['nomefiltrar'])) ? $_POST['nomefiltrar'] : "teste";
    $pessoas = filtraPessoas();
    $mpdf = new mPDF();
    $mpdf->setDisplayMode("fullpage");
    $mpdf->WriteHTML("<h1 align='center'>Relatório de Clientes</h1> <hr/>");

            $html = "
            <table class='tabela'>
            <thread>
                <tr>
                    <th>Nome</span></th>
                    <th>Data de nascimento</span></th>
                    <th>Telefone</th>
                    <th>Endereço</th>
                </tr>
            </thread>
            <tbody>
            ";
                foreach($pessoas as $pessoa){

                    $html = $html ." <tr>
                        <td align='center'> {$pessoa["nome"]} </td>
                        <td align='center'> {$pessoa["data_formatada"]} </td>
                        <td align='center'> {$pessoa["telefone"]} </td>
                        <td align='center'> {$pessoa["endereco"]} </td>
                    </tr>";
                }

                $html = $html ."
                </tbody>
                </table>
                <h1>{$nome_filtrar}</h1>
                ";

    $css = file_get_contents('pdf_estilo.css');
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($css, 1);
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $mpdf->Output();
    exit();

?>
```

Comment: sim a variável teste não foi enviada via $_POST, pois o formulário é enviado para consulta_clientes.php (logo ela entrara no else) , e sua função que preenche o post está em registra_pessoa.php. me corrija se eu estiver errado. Se for isso vou criar uma resposta de solução

Comment: Correto. Sei que parece ridiculo, mas teria como um form enviar os dados para duas páginas diferentes?

Comment: conheçe ajax? da pra fazer com ele, quando vc escreve o nome ele envia esse valor para uma pagina e retorna esse grupo. ou da pra fazer sem ajax mas ai é gambiarra. Qual voce quer?

Comment: manda um exemplo com ajax?

Comment: ok leticia,  eu somente não entendi uma coisa. Esse formulário ele vai consultar clientes baseado nesse nome que voce escrever? se sim então porque voce quer filtrar antes? ou então esse filtrar vai te dar uma lista de nomes que contem o que voce escreveu, e ai voce consulta os clientes por essa lista? Está usando jquery?

Comment: Esse formulário "filtroClientes" eu fiz para filtrar uma lista de nomes que contém o que escrever no campo "nomefiltrar", ele envia para a mesma página "consulta_clientes.php", essa página faz o select:
$grupo = filtraPessoas();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variável `$_POST['nomefiltrar'])` está vazia pois não foi enviado nada via post para a página `registra_pessoa.php`.

**Qual seria a solução**

Como seu formulário envia um submit para a mesma página você pode usar este código no inicio da pagina antes da chamada da função, para setar o valor de `nomefiltrar`:

```
$nome_filtrar = (isset($_POST['nomefiltrar'])) ? $_POST['nomefiltrar'] : "";
```

**O que isso faz?**

é um if escrito em forma mais compacta, ele verifica se foi enviado uma váriavel via post com o nome `nomefiltrar` se sim, ele atribui o valor se não ele coloca um valor vazio ( `''` );

**E Depois?**

Depois disso você pode implementar na sua função para ela receber esse valor como parâmetro:

```
$pessoas = filtraPessoas($nome_filtrar);

function filtraPessoas($nome){
    $grupo = '';
    $banco = abrirBanco();

    //lembrando que nome virá como o valor do input ou vazio
    $teste = $nome;

    $sql = "SELECT id, nome, DATE_FORMAT(nascimento, '%d/%m/%Y') AS data_formatada, endereco, telefone FROM pessoa WHERE nome LIKE '%$teste%' ";
    $resultado = $banco->query($sql);
    $banco->close();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
        $grupo[] = $row;
    }
    return $grupo;
}
```

Comment: Nem precisou do ajax, ao entender a situação, era apenas alterar algumas informações para que funcionasse. é claro que agora vc precisa fazer o uso correto do valor retornado pela variavel

Comment: Não deu certo. A página "pdf_clientes.php" ainda não recebe o valor da variável "nomefiltrar" para realizar o select no relatório

Comment: mas quem faz o select não é a função filtraPessoas() que está dentro de registra_pessoa.php? essa pagina ai que você falou é nova para min, nao está na pergunta

Comment: Sim, a página registra_pessoa.php tem a função select, a página pdf_clientes.php utiliza um require nessa página, mas não consegue obter os dados do "nomefiltrar", porque o post só vai para a página "consulta_clientes.php"

Comment: leticia é só fazer a mesma coisa, para as outras requires. se você nao colocar o que tem no seu código fica impossivel da gente te dar uma solução correta. fica a dica para as proximas perguntas

Comment: Mesmo colocando na outra página, não consegue recuperar o valor da variável. Se eu colocar:
$nome_filtrar = (isset($_POST['nomefiltrar'])) ? $_POST['nomefiltrar'] : "teste";

e printar isso:
<h1>{$nome_filtrar}</h1>

Ele retorna "teste". ainda não encontra o valor da variável. Vou editar o post com o codigo completo das pages

Comment: mas voce clicou no botao do submit, e o mesmo foi para a mesma pagina? ( tira o hidden do seu form) nao tem o porque dele né?

Comment: Sim, ele é hidden porque esse form com o button só aparece quando clica na imagem "filtrar resultados"
Dei um edit, coloquei o codigo completo

Comment: @Leticia bom, esta pergunta ja foi resolvida pela minha resposta, agora parar gerar esse pdf será mais facil fazer via uma requisição ajax. sugiro que abra uma outra pergunta, questionando sobre como gerar o pdf via ajax, passando a variavel nome. ficarei feliz em ajudar vc a resolve-la, mas o resto da sua duvida é de outra questao. finalize esta por gentileza